# Is there a Salt-equivalent to Puppet's Resource Default Statements?

Tags: saltstack, defaults

With Puppet you can set [Resource Default Statments](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/lang_defaults.html):

```
File {
  backup => '.puppet-bak',
  ensure => present,
  group  => 'root',
  mode   => '644',
  owner  => 'root',
}
```

and if I later have a `file` such as this it will inherit the default settings defined above.

```
file { '/etc/postfix/main.cf':
  source => "$file_root/etc/postfix/main.cf"
}
```

---

Is the same, or similar, possible with Salt to avoid a ton of duplicate code? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, it is not possible to set default resources like in puppet. The feature was approved, but there seems to be no information on if it was implemented yet. https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/6405

My suggestion is to use figure how to use jinja templating to satisfy this need.